# How do I access information from a Google Analytics Function via Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

My clients has Google Analytics on his site, which records what a customer has purchased, once the customer reaches the thank you page.

I need to get the product IDs and put them in a variable for facebook tracking.

I have access via GTM, but can not touch the actual source code.

The Google Analytics on the thank you page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Order Complet GA
ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
    'step': 6, 
});

ga('set', '&cu', 'EUR');

ga('ec:addProduct',{ 
        'id': '44', 
        'name': 'Zeobent MED® Detox-Pulver ultrafein 210g für 70 Tage',
        'category': 'Zeobent',
        'brand': 'Zeobent MED', 
        'price': '39.00', 
        'quantity': 1 
    }); 
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    id: '100120166',
    affiliation: 'ZeolithShop',
    revenue: '44.90',
    tax: '6.23',
    shipping: '5.90',
    coupon: ''
    });

//Auskommentiert weil Doppeltausgel�st 31.01.17 Tina SWA - ga('send', 'pageview', '/checkout-success');
```

How do I access what is inside `id` in `ec:addProduct`?

This code is generated as soon as the thank you page loads.

There is no data layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like that:

```
var matches = $('script:contains("ec:addProduct")').text().match(/'ec\:addProduct'\,{[ \n]+'id': '(.*?)'\,[ \n]+'name': '(.*?)'/);
if (matches != null && matches.length>=3)
{
   var id = matches[1];
   var name = matches[2];
}
```